# Need help identifying these plants, please!

Tags: identification

Please help me to identify these pretty plants!

[image]

Comment: These are different plants. Please ask a separate question for each plant. Thanks!

Comment: @NiallC.On the other hand, these are plants the commonly are found together, so a single question will IMO helps other users. The plant phytosociology is very important for identification of wild plants (and weed)

Comment: Welp the one front and center is clover, sometimes considered a weed other times used as a cover crop or even a lawn substitute.  The other with a pink flower might be swamp milkweed.  Then the lobed leaves look like dandelion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plant with white/rose flowers is [Polygonum aviculare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygonum_aviculare) (common knotgrass). Usually considered weed.

Additionally I would say Capsella bursa-pastoris, for the leaves behind, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

The three leaved plant (which I'm assuming you're asking about) looks like [Trifolium repens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trifolium_repens) (white clover).  Its an herbaceous perennial that grows where there a lack of nitrogen, and if often found in lawns.